# Unexpected behaviour in reassign variable in Elixir (binding operator)

Tags: elixir

In Elixir the "=" operator is the "binding" operator.
So I wonder why this piece of code works:

```
a = 0
a = a + 1
```

If we check the value of "a" is now 1.
I would have expected to see a binding error message something like:

```
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: 0
```

How works the rebind operation?

Comment: This should be a FAQ. You are not rebounding `a` in your sample code. You're silently creating a new `a`.Downvoted due to lack of any research.

Comment: Hi Onorio,I research a lot about this using iex. The problem is that is not cleare how rebind works in this case becase the expression a = a + 1 should be a pattern matching.

Comment: It's been asked over and over again.  If you had done any research you would have come across this because it's a very frequently asked question. Sorry--downvote stands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Elixir `=` is pattern matching operator. It checks that left hand side is equal to right hand side. 
However, it is also used to bind and rebind the variables. In your example the rebinding simply means "let `a` store now previous value of `a` + 1", which is trully similar to assignment in any other language.

To receive here `MatchError` you need to apply `^` (pin) operator, which do the pattern matching of the `exact value` underneath the label `a`.

```
iex(1)> a = 0
0
iex(2)> ^a = a
0
iex(3)> ^a = 0
0
iex(4)> ^a = a + 1
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: 1
```

I advise you to read [great article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/01/comparing-elixir-and-erlang-variables/) by José Valim about that.

TL;DR: Erlang doesn't allow to do rebinding, Elixir does. What's more important - Elixir's pattern matching requires to use `^` operator to have explicit match, otherwise you do the rebinding.

Binding it's just a "pointer" to the place in memory where the value is, so garbage collector knows that 0 is unused in your example.

Comment: Hi @PatNovak thanks for your reply. In my opion the "rebind" in this case generates more confusion than benefit :(

Comment: Well, it was not my decision, but it's a bit more similar to what *we* (OOP developers that felt in love with Elixir) had in previous languages. Honestly there are not many cases when you want to assign a variable again in Elixir, if you rely on pipeline and small functions.